# Having trouble understanding csv.reader

Tags: python, csv, google-analytics, google-search

Python newbie here so excuse my ignorance. I'm working with the Google Analytics Reporting API (v4) and Google Search Console API using scripts I found from [Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) and [this site](http://track-media.net/blog/getting-rid-of-not-provided.html).

The script tries to get basic analytics data like clicks and impressions both by page and by query and saves it into a csv file. Because this data is spread across 2 APIs the script fetches and saves the data separately and then uses a function `update_file(flags)` to combine the contents of 4 csv files. For example, one file has a list of all Google Search queries that generated impressions for the site in question. Flags here are the command-line arguments - site URL, start date, and end date.

```
def update_file(flags):
  #Combining all the data previously collected and stored in 3 seperate csv files into one global csv file
  print("Merging files")
  basic_url = flags.property_uri
  basic_url = basic_url.replace("://","_")
  basic_url = basic_url.replace(".","-")  
  
  matchfile ="Landingpage_analytics_"+flags.start_date+"_"+flags.end_date+"_"+basic_url+".csv"
  
  matchfile2 ='Landingpage_'+flags.start_date+"_"+flags.end_date+"_"+basic_url+".csv"
  matchfile3 ="Keyword_"+flags.start_date+"_"+flags.end_date+"_"+basic_url+".csv"
  csvfile="Landingpage_keyword_"+basic_url+"_"+flags.start_date+"_"+flags.end_date+".csv"
  newfile="Global_report_"+basic_url+"_"+flags.start_date+"_"+flags.end_date+".csv"
  print(matchfile)
  print(matchfile2)
  print(matchfile3)
  new_data=[] 
  new_data2=[]
  new_data3=[]
  with open(csvfile) as fin, open(matchfile) as fmatch, open(matchfile2) as fmatch2,
       open(matchfile3) as fmatch3, open(newfile,'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    checker = csv.reader(fmatch)
    checker2 = csv.reader(fmatch2)
    checker3 = csv.reader(fmatch3)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    header_reader = next(reader)
    next(checker)
    next(checker2)
    next(checker3)
    header_checker =["Clicks Keyword", "Impressions Keyword","Avg. Pos. Keyword","CTR Keyword",
                     "Clicks Landingpage","Impressions Landingpage","Avg. Pos. Landingpage",
                     "CTR Landingpage","GA Sessions","GA Bouncerate","GA Avg session duration","GA Avg. Pages/Session"]
    new_header = header_reader + header_checker
    writer.writerow(new_header)
    analytics = {}
    keyword = {}
    landingpage = {}

    for a in checker3:
      keyword[a[0]]=[a[2],a[1],a[3],float(a[2])/float(a[1])]

    for b in checker2:
      landingpage[b[0]]=[b[2],b[1],b[3],float(b[2])/float(b[1])]

    for xl in checker:
      url = flags.property_uri+xl[0]
      analytics[url] = [xl[1],float(xl[2])/float(xl[1]),xl[3],xl[4]]

    for i in reader:
      if i[0] in keyword:
        newrow = i + keyword[i[0]]
      else:
        # if keyword doesn't have specific data
        newrow = i + ['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
      new_data.append(newrow)

    for i in new_data:
      if i[1] in landingpage:
        newrow = i + landingpage[i[1]]
      else:
        # if landingpage doesn't have specific data
        newrow = i + ['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']      
      new_data2.append(newrow)


    for i in new_data2:
      if i[1] in analytics:
        newrow = i + analytics[i[1]]
        new_data3.append(newrow)  

    new_data3.sort(key=lambda row: float(row[2]), reverse=True)
    writer.writerows(new_data3)
```

The `update_file(flags)` function is not working and is generating an empty file. I tried debugging and discovered that the file referenced by `matchfile`, `fmatch`, and the csv reader `checker` has content before `update_file(flags)` is run, but is empty after.

```
for xl in checker:
      url = flags.property_uri+xl[0]
      analytics[url] = [xl[1],float(xl[2])/float(xl[1]),xl[3],xl[4]]
```

`analytics` stays empty after these lines, but `keyword` and `landingpage` contain the right data and use similar code. I'm not sure what's going on. Is there something I'm missing that could be causing these files to return empty?

Comment: There's no way this function could be changing the contents of any file other than `newfile`. Opening a file for reading cannot change it.

Comment: So you're saying you think the reason for the file in question being empty is outside this function (somewhere else in my code)? There's nothing here that could be causing the file referenced by `checker` and its output `analytics` to be empty?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.